# How can I iterate though files that I don't know the names or the quantity of?

Tags: c++, c, file

To give some context, I am letting the user drag files of his choice (as many as he'd like) to a folder that my program reads. How can my program find those files and reference them?

I am only looking for a function that does like following: `getUnknownFile(int index)` to return the file name or destination.

-Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide us a minimal example

Comment: Please pick one language, as solutions could be very different in different programming languages (C and C++ are two very different languages).

Comment: C++17 provides a very new [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) to inspect directories. Prior to this, you are bound to platform dependent (or third party) solutions. FYI: [SO: How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612097/7478597)

Comment: Since the order of the files may change while looping, you shuldn't use a numeric index as iterator.

Comment: I don't know any operating system which guarantees that the order of files if you get the list multiple times, which means a single index could give you different files at different times. So in short don't use indexes.

Comment: I initially was going to use C since it seems more simple but I think I'm going to try the idea of using C++17's filesystem libary. Thx all